# Verify JWT token in Next.js middleware throws Module not found: Can't resolve 'crypto' error

Tags: node.js, next.js, jwt, middleware

I'm trying to use JWT verification for authentication with middleware, but unfortunately, I'm getting some errors that cannot find a solution for.

```errors
./node_modules/jwa/index.js:3:0
Module not found: Can't resolve 'crypto'

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/jws/lib/sign-stream.js
./node_modules/jws/index.js
./node_modules/jsonwebtoken/verify.js
./middleware.ts

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found

You're using a Node.js module (crypto) which is not supported in the Edge Runtime.
Learn more: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/edge-runtime
```

**package.json**

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.9.3",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.9.3",
    "@mui/material": "^5.8.6",
    "@prisma/client": "^4.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "cookie": "^0.5.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "next": "12.2.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.33.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "18.0.0",
    "@types/react": "18.0.14",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.5",
    "eslint": "8.18.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.2.0",
    "prisma": "^4.0.0",
    "typescript": "4.7.4"
  }
}
```

**middleware.ts**

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import verify from "jsonwebtoken/verify";
import { urlToHttpOptions } from "url";
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server'

const secret = process.env.SECRET;

export default function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
    const { cookies } = req;
    const { search, protocol, host } = req.nextUrl

    const jwt = cookies.OutsiteJWT;
    const url = req.url;

    if (url.includes('/dashboard')) {
        if (jwt === undefined) {
            return NextResponse.redirect("http://localhost:3000/login");
        }

        try {
            verify(jwt, secret); // <---- ERROR COMES FROM HERE
            return NextResponse.next();
        } catch (error) {
            return NextResponse.redirect("/login");
        }
    }

    return NextResponse.next();
}
```

**/pages/api/auth/login.ts**

```ts
/* eslint-disable import/no-anonymous-default-export */
import { sign } from "jsonwebtoken";
import { serialize } from "cookie";

const secret = process.env.SECRET;

export default async function (req, res) {
    const { username, password } = req.body;

    // Check in the database
    // if a user with this username
    // and password exists
    if (username === "Admin" && password === "Admin") {
        const token = sign(
            {
                exp: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 60 * 60 * 24 * 30, // 30 days
                username: username,
            },
            secret
        );

        const serialised = serialize("OursiteJWT", token, {
            httpOnly: true,
            secure: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "development",
            sameSite: "strict",
            maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 30,
            path: "/",
        });

        res.setHeader("Set-Cookie", serialised);

        res.status(200).json({ message: "Success!" });
    } else {
        res.status(401).json({ message: "Invalid credentials!" });
    }
}
```

I've tried commenting out the *try/catch* to check if the token is set, and it works correctly, but when I try to verify in the middleware it fails.

In version 12.2.0 the [middleware](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/middleware) is stable but also has some changes.

Does somebody else encounter similar issues or know how to solve this?

Answer (score 7):

Based on the [discussion](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/38227) with a user in GitHub, apparently [jose](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jose) library works better while running Edge functions in the middleware while [jsonwebtoken](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken) does not.

**/middleware.ts**

```ts
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { urlToHttpOptions } from "url";
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server'
import { verify } from "./services/jwt_sign_verify";

const secret = process.env.SECRET || "secret";

export default async function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  const jwt = req.cookies.get("OutsiteJWT");
  const url = req.url;
  const {pathname} = req.nextUrl;

  if (pathname.startsWith("/dashboard")) {
    if (jwt === undefined) {
      req.nextUrl.pathname = "/login";
      return NextResponse.redirect(req.nextUrl);
    }

    try {
      await verify(jwt, secret);
      return NextResponse.next();
    } catch (error) {
      req.nextUrl.pathname = "/login";
      return NextResponse.redirect(req.nextUrl);
    }
  }

  return NextResponse.next();
}
```

**/services/jwt_sign_verify.ts**

```ts
import { SignJWT, jwtVerify, type JWTPayload } from 'jose';
import { Token } from "@typescript-eslint/types/dist/generated/ast-spec";

export async function sign(payload: string, secret: string): Promise<string> {
    const iat = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
    const exp = iat + 60 * 60; // one hour

    return new SignJWT({ payload })
        .setProtectedHeader({ alg: 'HS256', typ: 'JWT' })
        .setExpirationTime(exp)
        .setIssuedAt(iat)
        .setNotBefore(iat)
        .sign(new TextEncoder().encode(secret));
}

export async function verify(token: string, secret: string): Promise<JWTPayload> {
    const { payload } = await jwtVerify(token, new TextEncoder().encode(secret));
    // run some checks on the returned payload, perhaps you expect some specific values

    // if its all good, return it, or perhaps just return a boolean
    return payload;
}
```

**/pages/api/auth/login.ts**

```ts
/* eslint-disable import/no-anonymous-default-export */
import { serialize } from "cookie";
import { sign } from "../../../services/jwt_sign_verify";

const secret = process.env.SECRET || "secret";

export default async function (req, res) {
    const { username, password } = req.body;

    // Check in the database
    if (username === "Admin" && password === "Admin") {
        const token = await sign(
            "testing",
            secret
        );

        const serialised = serialize("OursiteJWT", token, {
            httpOnly: true,
            secure: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "development",
            sameSite: "strict",
            maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 30,
            path: "/",
        });

        res.setHeader("Set-Cookie", serialised);

        res.status(200).json({ message: "Success!" });
    } else {
        res.status(401).json({ message: "Invalid credentials!" });
    }
}
```